# Where does SharePoint store activated Features? ConfigDB or ContentDB?

Tags: sharepoint

I need to know whether SharePoint will restore the status of "activated" features when restoring from a catastrophic failure.

Presume the following
- Solution files are correctly deployed
- Config DB is unaffected

Specifically I am thinking at the webapp or site collection level.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so looks like it gets stored in the Content database. I can't find any documenation on this but there is a Features table in the database.